# Unable to connect to MSSQL database in a different domain

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

HI friends I wants to connect local server (linux) to a remote desktop's mssql database. I have reviewed the php document for assistance. 
It defines the use of mysql_connect().
I used that and ends with some issues mainly do to the difference in domain.

Here is the datas I have.

```
$dbname = 'dbname';  
$servername = 'servername.abc.cbd.net\instancename';  
$username = 'domain\username';  
$password = 'password';  
$port = '1433';
```

Here is the connection code I have used.

```
$link= mssql_connect($servername, $username, $password);  
if (!$link) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
```

Error am getting is

```
Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server:servername.abc.cbd.net\instancename
```

Please help me to correct the code. Is there any other alternative for myssql_connect().
Thanks in advance.

Comment: first rule - when you want to connect something on a remote server, you need to check if your system has the access rights to the remote system.

Comment: yes it has the access right. Also server is available.

Comment: you could try using PDO interface

Comment: Thats too I have tried and got error(111) from server.

Comment: username/ password are correct ?

Comment: yes username and password is correct.